# How use accelerometer in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, accelerometer, motion

I need help to use accelerometer with swift 3.

This is my code:

```
var motion = CMMotionManager()

@IBOutlet weak var statusAccel: UILabel!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    motion.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!){
        (data , error) in

        if let trueData = data {
            self.view.reloadInputViews()
            self.statusAccel.text = "\(trueData)"
        }
    }
}
```

It works but it just show me X Y and Z and i want to use Z.

Example : if Z = 2 do something

Comment: You want to use Z and get X,Y,Z. What is your problem? Do you need help with extracting the Z value from the triplet? On a side note, when you only analyse Z data, then it implies some assumptions on the calibration of the acclerometer and of the orientation before/during the movement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data` object that gets returned by `startAccelerometerUpdates(...)` is of type [`CMAccelerometerData`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmaccelerometerdata) which has a [`CMAcceleration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmacceleration) property. From this you can get the `z` component.

```
var motion = CMMotionManager()

@IBOutlet weak var statusAccel: UILabel!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    motion.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!){
        (data , error) in

        if let trueData = data {
            self.view.reloadInputViews()
            self.statusAccel.text = "\(trueData)"

            if trueData.acceleration.z == 2 {
                // do things...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean `if trueData.acceleration.z == 2`.

Comment: Where did you get that? `data` is of type `CMAccelerometerData`.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the acceleration on the Z-axis by calling `CMAccelerometerData.acceleration.z`. If you are unsure about how to access a certain property of a class, always check the documentation either in Xcode directly or on [Apple's documentation website](https://developer.apple.com/documentation), you can save a lot of time with this approach.

```
motion.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!, withHandler: { data, error in
    guard error == nil else { return }
    guard let accelerometerData = data else { return }
    if accelerometerData.acceleration.z == 2.0 {
        //do something
    }
})
```